# How to read specific lines from a text file in PHP

Tags: php, file, line

I have a txt file which has a lot of lines and the values in every line are separated with commas.

I want to read the 1st line alone which I did already using `fgets` :

```
$head = fgets(fopen($file, 'r'));
$headValues = explode(',', $head);
```

but now I want to read every other line from line 2 until the end of file and put those values into an array.

I searched for similar solutions but couldn't find any

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use descriptor

```
$fd = fopen($file, 'r');
$head = fgets($fd);
$headValues = explode(',', $head);
$data = [];

while(($str = fgets($fd)) !== false) {
  $otherValues = explode(',', $str); 
  $data[] = $otherValues;
}
```

Comment: This one only gets me the last line in the file for some reason

Answer (score 2):

This uses `fgetcsv` for the lines you care about and uses `array_combine` to put the headers and the line data together.

```
$fh = fopen($file, 'r');
$headValues = fgetcsv($fh);
$data = [];
while (true)    {
    if ( ($values = fgetcsv($fh)) === false ) {
        break;
    }
    $data[] = array_combine($headValues, $values);
    if ( fgets($fh) === false ) {
        break;
    }
}
fclose($fh);
print_r($data);
```

It checks at each read in case the EOF has been reached and then breaks out of the read loop.

Comment: D'oh! Processing every other line and not just the 2nd line on

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`file()`](http://php.net/file),  [`array_map()`](http://php.net/array_map) and [`array_shift()`](http://php.net/array_shift) :

```
$lines = file($file) ; // get file as array.
$lines = array_map(function($l){ return explode(',', $l); }, $lines);
$headValues = array_shift($lines); // get first values (removed from $lines)
```

So, `$lines` will contains all lines except the first one.

Comment: its expecting another argument in `array_map`